# understanding IIS Proxy response header rewrite Rule

Tags: xslt, iis, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

we have a IIS reverse proxy response rule, which modifies Location HTTP header.. I am trying to decode the logic and planning to write same logic in xslt, can someone explain below logic. how match pattern works and action rewrite and value works and what is R:1, R:2 , R:3 here ?

```
<rule name="Change Location Header" enabled="true">  
                <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_LOCATION" pattern="^http(s)?://([^/]+)/(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="true">
                    <add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="^301" />
                    <add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="^302" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://{R:2}/{R:3}" />
            </rule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule is changing the domain in the HTTP location header for redirect responses

**How is working match condition and what is R:1,R:2,R:3**

`RESPONSE_LOCATION` variable has full lik url. For example:

```
https://demo.cloudimg.io/s/width/300/sample.li/boat.jpg
```

In this case, after match operation with regexp: `^http(s)?://([^/]+)/(.*)`
Mathces will be like that:

```
{R:0}   https://demo.cloudimg.io/s/width/300/sample.li/boat.jpg
{R:1}   s
{R:2}   demo.cloudimg.io
{R:3}   s/width/300/sample.li/boat.jpg
```

Comment: Hi Victor, Thanks for the response, i really appreciate it. May i know what would be the modified Location Header value for https://demo.cloudimg.io/s/width/300/sample.li/boat.jpg

Comment: can samething be achieved using regex-replace in xslt as below      <xsl:variable name="LocationHeader_output">
  <xsl:value-of select="regexp:replace('https://demo.cloudimg.io/s/width/300/sample.li/boat.jpg', '^http(s)?://([^/]+)/(.*)', 'g', 'http{R:1}://{R:2}/{R:3}')" />
</xsl:variable>